# How to audit SQL Server 2008 queries through WCF Services?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, sql-server-2008, audit

I want to save any kind of log/tables with every query executed by my application.

I know I could do this by coding it (before I make any query, I insert a new row in a log table with the query and the user who is executing it.

I have read it can be done automatically but I'm not sure how can it work with WCF Services. I mean every query is going to be executed by the same SQL user and this wouldn't be very useful for audit operations (I need to know WHO made every query, and users will be validated against my own users tables).

Have you ever had a similar scenario? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point it may be worth looking into doing this via [SQL Server Profiler](http://Using%20SQL%20Server%20Profiler). You can normally find this in the Tools Menu in Management Studio.

You can set up a trace to capture all SQL run on a server.  More importantly you have a myriad of filter options which can be applied so that you only capture the data you are interested in (e.g. DatabaseName, UserName).

This information can be stored directly in a SQL Table, which should give you the abillity to join onto.  Of course running anything like this will result in some overhead on the SQL box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [SQL Server Audit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) feature. It audits singe or groups of events both on server and database level. However, be advised that the database level auditing is available in SQL Server Enterprise and Developer editions only